# Why bootstrap import doesn't include mixins

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I built a Vue app using `Vue cli` and installed `Bootstrap v4.3.1` for style. I am including bootstrap in an scss file like this

`@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';`

Considering bootstrap classes are working, I am guessing it is being imported successfully. But when I tried using mixin, it threw error

`No mixin named media-breakpoint-up`.

I checked bootstrap inside node_modules, and it seems like the import 
`@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';` should have imported mixins as well.

I don't understand what is going wrong here.

Comment: Please have a look on the above link, maybe your question is already answered there. And Welcome to SO BTW. ;)

Comment: Thanks Ahmad, yes that link solved my problem :)

Comment: And BTW, since you seem new to Stackoverflow ( I assume from your reputation), it's good to search for any similar question before asking it yourself. Because that way, other users may give you a downvote that will reduce your reputation. I am a newbie too :)